# Utils can not be resolved in Android Opencv

Tags: android, opencv

i am trying to multiple template match in android. I have write a code but in this code when i try to use "Utils" For converting matToBitmap. It says Utils can not be reosolved. I added JRE System Library.Import many package but nothing fix this. here is my code:

```
package com.example.tryapp;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

[I imported all of this package one by one but none of this work][1]


public class tmpmatch extends Activity{

 static  void match()
{

int match_method=Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF;
String img ="res/drawable/lena.png";
String tm1img ="res/drawable/those_eyes.png";
String tm2img ="res/drawable/eye2.png";
String outFile="res/drawable/tmp.png";
Mat mimg=Imgcodecs.imread(img);
Mat mtm1img=Imgcodecs.imread(tm1img);
Mat mtm2img=Imgcodecs.imread(tm2img);
int result_cols = mimg.cols() - mtm1img.cols() + 1;
int result_rows = mimg.rows() - mtm1img.rows() + 1;
int result_cols2 = mimg.cols() - mtm2img.cols() + 1;
int result_rows2 = mimg.rows() - mtm2img.rows() + 1;
Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);
Mat result2 = new Mat(result_rows2, result_cols2, CvType.CV_32FC1);

Imgproc.matchTemplate(mimg, mtm1img, result,Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF);
Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
Imgproc.matchTemplate(mimg, mtm2img, result2, Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF);
Core.normalize(result2, result2, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
MinMaxLocResult mmr2 = Core.minMaxLoc(result2);

Point matchLoc,matchLoc2;
if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
    matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
    matchLoc2 = mmr2.minLoc;
} else {
    matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    matchLoc2 = mmr2.maxLoc;
}

// / Show me what you got
Imgproc.rectangle(mimg, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + mtm1img.cols(),
        matchLoc.y + mtm1img.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
Imgproc.rectangle(mimg, matchLoc2, new Point(matchLoc2.x + mtm2img.cols(),
        matchLoc2.y + mtm2img.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));


// Save the visualized detection.
//System.out.println("Writing "+ outFile);
//Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile, mimg);
//System.out.println("written");

Mat android_image = Mat.zeros(mimg.cols(), mimg.rows(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

Imgproc.cvtColor(mimg, android_image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(android_image.cols(),android_image.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Utils.matToBitmap(android_image, bm);

ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
iv.setImageBitmap(bm);


}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
        match();

}
```

}

Comment: Please Help me out i am stuck here. I am using opencv 3.00

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you. For me, firstly I imported the opencv-androidsdk 3.0.0 as a existing project to my eclipse workspace. After that I added that sdk as the library to my project then the problem is solved. No more error for utils.matToBitmap(mat,bitmap). Hope this useful for you.

This is the link that I used. 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html